# In .NET NEST Elasticsearch how to append Match term conditionally?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am using .net core 3.1 and NEST latest version. My requirement is to build the query and add Match term if `param.Name/param.Type` has value. If `param.Name/param.Type` has no value, I need to ignore them. How can I achieve it? What I have done is provided below:

```
var response = esClient.Search<CustomDataModel>(s => s
                .Index(index)
                .Size(1000)
                .Query(q => q
                        .Match(m=>m.Field(f=>f.Name).Query(param.Name)) && q
                        .Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Type).Query(param.Type)) && q
                        .Match(m=>m.Field(f=>f.Country).Query(string.Join(" ",param.Countries)))))
                )
```

What I want is like

```
if(param.Name!=null){
//add .Match(m=>m.Field(f=>f.Name).Query(param.Name)) to the q.
}
if(param.Type!=null){
//add .Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Type).Query(param.Type)) to the q.
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try with QueryContainer?